# Buttons don't work when I place them outside the carousel

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have this code and when I put the anchor (arrow img) outside, `.MultiCarousel` div it doesn't work. I didn't write the code but I think I should change something in JavaScript. I want the anchor outside the container div but with the same functionality. I am not very familiar with JavaScript so I don't know what to change. Can someone help?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var itemsMainDiv = ('.MultiCarousel');
    var itemsDiv = ('.MultiCarousel-inner');
    var itemWidth = "";

    $('.leftLst, .rightLst').click(function () {
        var condition = $(this).hasClass("leftLst");
        if (condition)
            click(0, this);
        else
            click(1, this)
    });

    ResCarouselSize();

    $(window).resize(function () {
        ResCarouselSize();
    });

    //this function define the size of the items
    function ResCarouselSize() {
        var incno = 0;
        var dataItems = ("data-items");
        var itemClass = ('.item');
        var id = 0;
        var btnParentSb = '';
        var itemsSplit = '';
        var sampwidth = $(itemsMainDiv).width();
        var bodyWidth = $('body').width();
        $(itemsDiv).each(function () {
            id = id + 1;
            var itemNumbers = $(this).find(itemClass).length;
            btnParentSb = $(this).parent().attr(dataItems);
            itemsSplit = btnParentSb.split(',');
            $(this).parent().attr("id", "MultiCarousel" + id);

            if (bodyWidth >= 1200) {
                incno = itemsSplit[3];
                itemWidth = sampwidth / incno;
            }
            else if (bodyWidth >= 992) {
                incno = itemsSplit[2];
                itemWidth = sampwidth / incno;
            }
            else if (bodyWidth >= 768) {
                incno = itemsSplit[1];
                itemWidth = sampwidth / incno;
            }
            else {
                incno = itemsSplit[0];
                itemWidth = sampwidth / incno;
            }
            $(this).css({ 'transform': 'translateX(0px)', 'width': itemWidth * itemNumbers });
            $(this).find(itemClass).each(function () {
                $(this).outerWidth(itemWidth);
            });

            $(".leftLst").addClass("over");
            $(".rightLst").removeClass("over");

        });
    }


    //this function used to move the items
    function ResCarousel(e, el, s) {
        var leftBtn = ('.leftLst');
        var rightBtn = ('.rightLst');
        var translateXval = '';
        var divStyle = $(el + ' ' + itemsDiv).css('transform');
        var values = divStyle.match(/-?[\d\.]+/g);
        var xds = Math.abs(values[4]);
        if (e == 0) {
            translateXval = parseInt(xds) - parseInt(itemWidth * s);
            $(el).siblings(rightBtn).removeClass("over");

            if (translateXval <= itemWidth / 2) {
                translateXval = 0;
                $(el).siblings(leftBtn).addClass("over");
            }
        }
        else if (e == 1) {
            var itemsCondition = $(el).find(itemsDiv).width() - $(el).width();
            translateXval = parseInt(xds) + parseInt(itemWidth * s);
            $(el).siblings(leftBtn).removeClass("over");

            if (translateXval >= itemsCondition - itemWidth / 2) {
                translateXval = itemsCondition;
                $(el).siblings(rightBtn).addClass("over");
            }
        }
        $(el + ' ' + itemsDiv).css('transform', 'translateX(' + -translateXval + 'px)');
    }

    //It is used to get some elements from btn
    function click(ell, ee) {
        var Parent = "#" + $(ee).siblings( '.MultiCarousel' ).attr("id");
        var slide = $(Parent).attr("data-slide");
        ResCarousel(ell, Parent, slide);
    }
});
```

```css
.MultiCarousel { 
    float: left; 
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 15px; 
    width: 100%; 
    position:relative; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.MultiCarousel .MultiCarousel-inner {
    transition: 1s ease all;
    float: left; 
}
.MultiCarousel .MultiCarousel-inner .item { 
    float: left;
}
.MultiCarousel .MultiCarousel-inner .item > div { 
    text-align: center;
    padding:10px;
    margin:10px;  
    color:#666;
}
.leftLst, .rightLst { 
    position:absolute;
    border-radius:50%;
    top:calc(50% - 20px);
    background: red;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
.leftLst {
    left:0; 
}
.rightLst {
    right:0; 
}

.leftLst.over,  .rightLst.over {
    pointer-events: none; 
    background:#ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="MultiCarousel" data-items="1,2,3,4" data-slide="1" id="MultiCarousel"  data-interval="1000">
              <div class="MultiCarousel-inner">
                  <div class="item">
                        <div class="col-xl-3 pad15">
                          <img src="images/cert4.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                          <div class="onhover"><span>Certifikata per Atesimin e Kaldajes Elektrike</span></div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="item">
                    <div class="col-xl-3 pad15"> 
                      <img src="images/cert2.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                      <div class="onhover"><span>Certifikata per Atesimin e Kaldajes Elektrike</span></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="item">
                    <div class="col-xl-3 pad15">
                      <img src="images/cert3.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                      <div class="onhover"><span>Certifikata per Atesimin e Kaldajes Elektrike</span></div>
                  </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="item">
                    <div class="col-xl-3 pad15">
                      <img src="images/cert7.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                      <div class="onhover"><span>Certifikata per Atesimin e Kaldajes Elektrike</span></div>    
                  </div> 
                  </div>
                  <div class="item">
                    <div class="col-xl-3 pad15">
                      <img src="images/cert4.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                      <div class="onhover"><span>Certifikata per Atesimin e Kaldajes Elektrike</span></div>
                  </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="item">
                    <div class="col-xl-3 pad15"> 
                      <img src="images/cert2.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                      <div class="onhover"><span>Certifikata per Atesimin e Kaldajes Elektrike</span></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="item">
                    <div class="col-xl-3 pad15">
                      <img src="images/cert3.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                      <div class="onhover"><span>Certifikata per Atesimin e Kaldajes Elektrike</span></div>
                  </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="item">
                    <div class="col-xl-3 pad15">
                      <img src="images/cert7.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                      <div class="onhover"><span>Certifikata per Atesimin e Kaldajes Elektrike</span></div>    
                  </div> 
                  </div>
              </div>
              <a class=" leftLst"><img src="images/left_arrow.svg" alt=""></a>
              <a class=" rightLst"><img src="images/right_arrow.svg" alt=""></a>
          </div>
       
    </div>
  
  </div>
```

Comment: Please add snippet. Your code not working

Comment: https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/zDQkr here I saw the code I just modify html a little

Comment: Can you please convert your code to Code snippet or use external resource like https://jsfiddle.net so it will be easier for us to point the problem. Thanks

Comment: I just added an alternative solution which might be a better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `click()` function is searching for the parent element of the arrow key button, which it expects to be the `.MultiCarousel` div in order for the rest of the code to work. So when you place the arrow keys outside of the `.MultiCarousel` div a different parent will be found and your slider will not work.

In this case you could use the jQuery `siblings()` function to find the `.MultiCarousel` div, as the arrow key buttons are now siblings.

The same goes for the `ResCarousel()` function. It expects the arrow key buttons to be children of the `.MultiCarousel` div. So you can also use `siblings()` here.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var itemsMainDiv = ('.MultiCarousel');
    var itemsDiv = ('.MultiCarousel-inner');
    var itemWidth = "";

    $('.leftLst, .rightLst').click(function () {
        var condition = $(this).hasClass("leftLst");
        if (condition)
            click(0, this);
        else
            click(1, this)
    });

    ResCarouselSize();

    $(window).resize(function () {
        ResCarouselSize();
    });

    //this function define the size of the items
    function ResCarouselSize() {
        var incno = 0;
        var dataItems = ("data-items");
        var itemClass = ('.item');
        var id = 0;
        var btnParentSb = '';
        var itemsSplit = '';
        var sampwidth = $(itemsMainDiv).width();
        var bodyWidth = $('body').width();
        $(itemsDiv).each(function () {
            id = id + 1;
            var itemNumbers = $(this).find(itemClass).length;
            btnParentSb = $(this).parent().attr(dataItems);
            itemsSplit = btnParentSb.split(',');
            $(this).parent().attr("id", "MultiCarousel" + id);

            if (bodyWidth >= 1200) {
                incno = itemsSplit[3];
                itemWidth = sampwidth / incno;
            }
            else if (bodyWidth >= 992) {
                incno = itemsSplit[2];
                itemWidth = sampwidth / incno;
            }
            else if (bodyWidth >= 768) {
                incno = itemsSplit[1];
                itemWidth = sampwidth / incno;
            }
            else {
                incno = itemsSplit[0];
                itemWidth = sampwidth / incno;
            }
            $(this).css({ 'transform': 'translateX(0px)', 'width': itemWidth * itemNumbers });
            $(this).find(itemClass).each(function () {
                $(this).outerWidth(itemWidth);
            });

            $(".leftLst").addClass("over");
            $(".rightLst").removeClass("over");

        });
    }


    //this function used to move the items
    function ResCarousel(e, el, s) {
        var leftBtn = ('.leftLst');
        var rightBtn = ('.rightLst');
        var translateXval = '';
        var divStyle = $(el + ' ' + itemsDiv).css('transform');
        var values = divStyle.match(/-?[\d\.]+/g);
        var xds = Math.abs(values[4]);
        if (e == 0) {
            translateXval = parseInt(xds) - parseInt(itemWidth * s);
            $(el).siblings(rightBtn).removeClass("over");

            if (translateXval <= itemWidth / 2) {
                translateXval = 0;
                $(el).siblings(leftBtn).addClass("over");
            }
        }
        else if (e == 1) {
            var itemsCondition = $(el).find(itemsDiv).width() - $(el).width();
            translateXval = parseInt(xds) + parseInt(itemWidth * s);
            $(el).siblings(leftBtn).removeClass("over");

            if (translateXval >= itemsCondition - itemWidth / 2) {
                translateXval = itemsCondition;
                $(el).siblings(rightBtn).addClass("over");
            }
        }
        $(el + ' ' + itemsDiv).css('transform', 'translateX(' + -translateXval + 'px)');
    }

    //It is used to get some elements from btn
    function click(ell, ee) {
        var Parent = "#" + $(ee).siblings( '.MultiCarousel' ).attr("id");
        var slide = $(Parent).attr("data-slide");
        ResCarousel(ell, Parent, slide);
    }
});
```

```css
.MultiCarousel { 
    float: left; 
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 15px; 
    width: 100%; 
    position:relative; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.MultiCarousel .MultiCarousel-inner {
    transition: 1s ease all;
    float: left; 
}
.MultiCarousel .MultiCarousel-inner .item { 
    float: left;
}
.MultiCarousel .MultiCarousel-inner .item > div { 
    text-align: center;
    padding:10px;
    margin:10px;  
    color:#666;
}
.leftLst, .rightLst { 
    position:absolute;
    border-radius:50%;
    top:calc(50% - 20px);
    background: red;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
.leftLst {
    left:0; 
}
.rightLst {
    right:0; 
}

.leftLst.over,  .rightLst.over {
    pointer-events: none; 
    background:#ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="MultiCarousel" data-items="1,2,3,4" data-slide="1" id="MultiCarousel"  data-interval="1000">
            <div class="MultiCarousel-inner">
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="col-xl-3 pad15">
                        <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/360" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                        <div class="onhover"><span>Certifikata per Atesimin e Kaldajes Elektrike</span></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="col-xl-3 pad15"> 
                        <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/360" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                        <div class="onhover"><span>Certifikata per Atesimin e Kaldajes Elektrike</span></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="col-xl-3 pad15">
                        <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/360" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                        <div class="onhover"><span>Certifikata per Atesimin e Kaldajes Elektrike</span></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="col-xl-3 pad15">
                        <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/360" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                        <div class="onhover"><span>Certifikata per Atesimin e Kaldajes Elektrike</span></div>    
                    </div> 
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="col-xl-3 pad15">
                        <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/360" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                        <div class="onhover"><span>Certifikata per Atesimin e Kaldajes Elektrike</span></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="col-xl-3 pad15"> 
                        <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/360" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                        <div class="onhover"><span>Certifikata per Atesimin e Kaldajes Elektrike</span></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="col-xl-3 pad15">
                        <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/360" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                        <div class="onhover"><span>Certifikata per Atesimin e Kaldajes Elektrike</span></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="col-xl-3 pad15">
                        <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/360" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                        <div class="onhover"><span>Certifikata per Atesimin e Kaldajes Elektrike</span></div>    
                    </div> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <a class=" leftLst"><img src="images/left_arrow.svg" alt=""></a>
        <a class=" rightLst"><img src="images/right_arrow.svg" alt=""></a>

    </div>
</div>
```

### Alternative solution

Your question stated specifically that you wanted to place the arrow key buttons outside the `.MultiCarousel` div but I think it might be better to keep them inside the div as it functions as a wrapper for the whole carousel.

You can then use the `closest()` function to find the `.MultiCarousel` div in the `click()` function, and the `find()` function to find the buttons in the `ResCarousel()` function.

This way the buttons are always connected to the correct slider, for instance when you want to use multiple sliders next to each other, as in the example below.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var itemsMainDiv = ('.MultiCarousel');
    var itemsDiv = ('.MultiCarousel-inner');
    var itemWidth = "";

    $('.leftLst, .rightLst').click(function () {
        var condition = $(this).hasClass("leftLst");
        if (condition)
            click(0, this);
        else
            click(1, this)
    });

    ResCarouselSize();

    $(window).resize(function () {
        ResCarouselSize();
    });

    //this function define the size of the items
    function ResCarouselSize() {
        var incno = 0;
        var dataItems = ("data-items");
        var itemClass = ('.item');
        var id = 0;
        var btnParentSb = '';
        var itemsSplit = '';
        var sampwidth = $(itemsMainDiv).width();
        var bodyWidth = $('body').width();
        $(itemsDiv).each(function () {
            id = id + 1;
            var itemNumbers = $(this).find(itemClass).length;
            btnParentSb = $(this).parent().attr(dataItems);
            itemsSplit = btnParentSb.split(',');
            $(this).parent().attr("id", "MultiCarousel" + id);

            if (bodyWidth >= 1200) {
                incno = itemsSplit[3];
                itemWidth = sampwidth / incno;
            }
            else if (bodyWidth >= 992) {
                incno = itemsSplit[2];
                itemWidth = sampwidth / incno;
            }
            else if (bodyWidth >= 768) {
                incno = itemsSplit[1];
                itemWidth = sampwidth / incno;
            }
            else {
                incno = itemsSplit[0];
                itemWidth = sampwidth / incno;
            }
            $(this).css({ 'transform': 'translateX(0px)', 'width': itemWidth * itemNumbers });
            $(this).find(itemClass).each(function () {
                $(this).outerWidth(itemWidth);
            });

            $(".leftLst").addClass("over");
            $(".rightLst").removeClass("over");

        });
    }


    //this function used to move the items
    function ResCarousel(e, el, s) {
        var leftBtn = ('.leftLst');
        var rightBtn = ('.rightLst');
        var translateXval = '';
        var divStyle = $(el + ' ' + itemsDiv).css('transform');
        var values = divStyle.match(/-?[\d\.]+/g);
        var xds = Math.abs(values[4]);
        if (e == 0) {
            translateXval = parseInt(xds) - parseInt(itemWidth * s);
            $(el).find(rightBtn).removeClass("over");

            if (translateXval <= itemWidth / 2) {
                translateXval = 0;
                $(el).find(leftBtn).addClass("over");
            }
        }
        else if (e == 1) {
            var itemsCondition = $(el).find(itemsDiv).width() - $(el).width();
            translateXval = parseInt(xds) + parseInt(itemWidth * s);
            $(el).find(leftBtn).removeClass("over");

            if (translateXval >= itemsCondition - itemWidth / 2) {
                translateXval = itemsCondition;
                $(el).find(rightBtn).addClass("over");
            }
        }
        $(el + ' ' + itemsDiv).css('transform', 'translateX(' + -translateXval + 'px)');
    }

    //It is used to get some elements from btn
    function click(ell, ee) {
        var Parent = "#" + $(ee).closest( '.MultiCarousel' ).attr("id");
        var slide = $(Parent).attr("data-slide");
        ResCarousel(ell, Parent, slide);
    }
});
```

```css
.MultiCarousel { 
    float: left; 
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 5%; 
    width: 40%; 
    position:relative; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.MultiCarousel .MultiCarousel-inner {
    transition: 1s ease all;
    float: left; 
}
.MultiCarousel .MultiCarousel-inner .item { 
    float: left;
}
.MultiCarousel .MultiCarousel-inner .item > div { 
    text-align: center;
    padding:10px;
    margin:10px;  
    color:#666;
}
.leftLst, .rightLst { 
    /*position:absolute;*/
    border-radius:50%;
    /*top:calc(50% - 20px);*/
    background: red;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    display: block;
}
.leftLst {
    float: left; 
}
.rightLst {
    float: right;
}

.leftLst.over,  .rightLst.over {
    pointer-events: none; 
    background:#ccc;
}

.buttons {
    width: 100%;
    clear:both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        
        <div class="MultiCarousel" data-items="1,2,3,4" data-slide="1" id="MultiCarousel"  data-interval="1000">
            <div class="MultiCarousel-inner">
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="col-xl-3 pad15">
                        <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/200/200" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                        <div class="onhover"><span>Certifikata per Atesimin e Kaldajes Elektrike</span></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="col-xl-3 pad15"> 
                        <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/200/200" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                        <div class="onhover"><span>Certifikata per Atesimin e Kaldajes Elektrike</span></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="col-xl-3 pad15">
                        <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/200/200" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                        <div class="onhover"><span>Certifikata per Atesimin e Kaldajes Elektrike</span></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="col-xl-3 pad15">
                        <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/200/200" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                        <div class="onhover"><span>Certifikata per Atesimin e Kaldajes Elektrike</span></div>    
                    </div> 
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="col-xl-3 pad15">
                        <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/200/200" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                        <div class="onhover"><span>Certifikata per Atesimin e Kaldajes Elektrike</span></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="col-xl-3 pad15"> 
                        <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/200/200" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                        <div class="onhover"><span>Certifikata per Atesimin e Kaldajes Elektrike</span></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="col-xl-3 pad15">
                        <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/200/200" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                        <div class="onhover"><span>Certifikata per Atesimin e Kaldajes Elektrike</span></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="col-xl-3 pad15">
                        <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/200/200" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                        <div class="onhover"><span>Certifikata per Atesimin e Kaldajes Elektrike</span></div>    
                    </div> 
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="buttons">
                <a class=" leftLst"><img src="images/left_arrow.svg" alt=""></a>
                <a class=" rightLst"><img src="images/right_arrow.svg" alt=""></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="MultiCarousel" data-items="1,2,3,4" data-slide="1" id="MultiCarousel"  data-interval="1000">
            <div class="MultiCarousel-inner">
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="col-xl-3 pad15">
                        <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/200/200" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                        <div class="onhover"><span>Certifikata per Atesimin e Kaldajes Elektrike</span></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="col-xl-3 pad15"> 
                        <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/200/200" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                        <div class="onhover"><span>Certifikata per Atesimin e Kaldajes Elektrike</span></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="col-xl-3 pad15">
                        <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/200/200" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                        <div class="onhover"><span>Certifikata per Atesimin e Kaldajes Elektrike</span></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="col-xl-3 pad15">
                        <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/200/200" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                        <div class="onhover"><span>Certifikata per Atesimin e Kaldajes Elektrike</span></div>    
                    </div> 
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="col-xl-3 pad15">
                        <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/200/200" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                        <div class="onhover"><span>Certifikata per Atesimin e Kaldajes Elektrike</span></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="col-xl-3 pad15"> 
                        <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/200/200" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                        <div class="onhover"><span>Certifikata per Atesimin e Kaldajes Elektrike</span></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="col-xl-3 pad15">
                        <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/200/200" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                        <div class="onhover"><span>Certifikata per Atesimin e Kaldajes Elektrike</span></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="col-xl-3 pad15">
                        <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/200/200" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                        <div class="onhover"><span>Certifikata per Atesimin e Kaldajes Elektrike</span></div>    
                    </div> 
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="buttons">
                <a class=" leftLst"><img src="images/left_arrow.svg" alt=""></a>
                <a class=" rightLst"><img src="images/right_arrow.svg" alt=""></a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```